# method in React just for the first Mounting component

Tags: reactjs

Is something like method working like ComponentDidMount, but is calling just in the **first mounting** not for every?

Comment: Why do you want to treat specially the first time the component mounts?

Comment: The problem is that component is destroyed, and then the next time that it be rendered it's created again. Additionally, it's not a good practice to use rendering side effects to control application logic and state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not function like this. However, you can keep track of how many times a component mounts in its parent state and with a callback function. Alternatively, the parent can send a flag that indicates what the child should render.